# Why doesn't this SQL query work with the .net Entity Framwork?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

I'm writing this code in the Entity Framework.  I understand that normally, you don't query SQL directly using the Entity Framework, but for the life of me, I can't understand why this code doesn't work

```
ucvDotNet.Models.CdaSql entities = new Models.CdaSql();
object X = entities.CreateQuery<Lids>("select * from lids").First();
```

I get an error message that says that `*` is invalid syntax.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework doesn't use regular SQL, it uses [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738683.aspx) which does not have the `SELECT * FROM` syntax.

Comment: +1 though I this link is probably more to the point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738573.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular SQL with `ExecuteStoreQuery()` instead:

```
var item = entities.ExecuteStoreQuery<Lids>("select * from lids")
                   .First();
```

Since everything from `ExecuteStoreQuery()` is materialized to a bunch of `Lids` objects the above should be rewritten as:

```
var item = entities.ExecuteStoreQuery<Lids>("select top 1 * from lids")
                   .First();
```